# docker-compose up, down, stop start difference

Tags: docker-compose

I cant find more information about those.

Should we use `docker stop` for containers which we started with `docker start`

Or same for `docker-compose up`?

What is the difference between stop and down?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In docker-compose help

```
stop               Stop services

down               Stop and remove containers and networks (optionally images and volumes as well)
```

Comment: `docker-compose down` does not remove `images` and `volumes` by default. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

Comment: for removing the volumes also, you should use `-v` option, so it would be `docker-compose down -v`

Answer (score 109):

```
# Stop services only
docker-compose stop

# Stop and remove containers, networks..
docker-compose down 

# Down and remove volumes
docker-compose down --volumes 

# Down and remove images
docker-compose down --rmi <all|local>
```

Comment: The "local" option in the last command is defined as "Remove only images that don't have a custom tag". https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_down/

Answer (score 27):

Following are the differences among various `docker-compose` command options:

`docker-compose up` - start and restart all the services defined in docker-compose.yml

`docker-compose down` - command will stop running containers, but it also removes the stopped containers as well as any networks that were created. You can take down one step further and add the `-v` flag to remove all volumes too. This is great for doing a full blown reset on your environment by running `docker-compose down -v`.

`docker-compose start` - command will only restart containers stopped previously

`docker-compose restart` - command will restart all stopped and running containers

`docker-compose stop` - command will stop running containers but won’t remove them

Answer (score 11):

Just to answer the other part of the question:

Use `docker-compose up` to start or restart all the services defined in a `docker-compose.yml`.

The `docker-compose start` command is useful only to restart containers that were previously created, but were stopped. It never creates new containers.

The `docker-compose run` command is for running “one-off” or “adhoc” tasks.

For further information visit [this page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-up-run-and-start).