# How do I stop them from starting automatically without deleting the containers?

Tags: docker

I built some docker images from [a YAML file](https://github.com/IndustryEssentials/label-free/blob/main/docker-compose.yml) with the command `docker-compose up -d` a few days ago, now every time I restart my Ubuntu a bunch of containers start automatically. How do I stop them from starting automatically without deleting the containers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose up, down, stop start difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428420/docker-compose-up-down-stop-start-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `restart:always` line(s). `restart: unless-stopped` could help you.

You can update them like this:

```
 docker update --restart unless-stopped <name-of-your-container>
```

Comment: For further information: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/